# How to put wood in the /fill command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, the /fill command doesn't seem to have wood. Does anyone know a way to use wood in the /fill comand?

Comment: What is the command you are trying? Edit your question to include it.

Comment: He just said "/fill"... @TimmyJim

Comment: @John Yes, and has shown no attempt to solve it.  Showing what you've tried is rather important.

Comment: Why would asking for the ID of wood require any previously tried commands?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13507/4797) - especially the part about "what you've tried so far."

Answer (score 2):

The command *does* have wood. Wood has the internal name of "minecraft:log" for normal varieties and "minecraft:log2" for Acacia and Dark Oak. Just type:

```
    /fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> minecraft:log
```